# How do i pass arguments while running a bat file in Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, parameter-passing

I want to run a bat file located in a specific location with some parameters.

If i cd to that location and then run the bat file with arguments, it works in command prompt. But how do i run it with absolute path in Jenkins?

I want to do something like this

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\soapUI-4.5.2\bin\testrunner.bat C:\Dev\COM\B2B\Vishal\SOAPUIGIT\B2bSoapUI.xml -s"Amend Order New Framework" -M"

however this gives an error saying
**"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."**

Comment: are you running this command in "Execute Windows Batch Command" Section ?

Comment: Yes, i am running it from "Execute Windows Batch Command" Section.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

The issue was with the double quotes.

Changing it to this worked 
call **"C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\soapUI-4.5.2\bin\testrunner.bat" C:\Dev\COM\B2B\Vishal\SOAPUIGIT\B2bSoapUI.xml -s"Amend Order New Framework" -M**